# problems in duplicating a object/ creating a object through python API

Tags: python

I created a city scene which has a vehicle model inside, I need to duplicate the vehicle model to display a dozen of them in the city scene through python API. The vehicle object name is BMWM1. I have tried on these two approaches
[image]
Approach 1 [from stackoverflow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45099/duplicating-a-mesh-object)

```
scn = bpy.context.scene
new_obj = bpy.data.objects["BMWM1"].copy()
new_obj.data = bpy.data.objects["BMWM1"].data.copy()
new_obj.animation_data_clear()
scn.objects.link(new_obj)
new_obj.location = (-8, 6, 2)
scn.objects.active = new_obj
new_obj.select = True
```

Approach 2

```
bpy.data.objects['BMWM1'].select = True
new_obj = bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
scn.objects.link(new_obj)
new_obj.location = (-8, 6, 2)
scn.objects.active = new_obj
new_obj.select = True
```

Both approaches received a error saying

> "warning DM_ensure_tessface: could not create tessfaces from 144
>   polygons, dm->type=2 warning DM_ensure_tessface: could not create
>   tessfaces from 144 polygons, dm->type=2 "

And the second approach additionally received a error:

> "    scn.objects.link(new_obj) TypeError: SceneObjects.link(): error
>   with argument 1, "object" -  Function.object expected a Object type,
>   not set "

I have also seen the tutorials like [Three ways to create objects](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects), two ways to create a new object

```
Add the data, and then the object. For a mesh: 

me = bpy.data.meshes.new(meshName)
ob = bpy.data.objects.new(obName, me)
```

and for an armature:

```
amt = bpy.data.armatures.new(amtname)
ob = bpy.data.objects.new(obname, amt)
```

While I tried [another way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/duplicating-non-primitive-mesh-with-python)

```
me = bpy.data.objects["BMWM1"].data;
me_copy = me.copy()
new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("BMWM1",me_copy)

scn.objects.link(new_obj)
new_obj.location = (-8, 6, 2)
scn.objects.active = new_obj
new_obj.select = True
```

but still at the end the error

> "warning DM_ensure_tessface: could not create tessfaces from 144
>   polygons, dm->type=2 warning DM_ensure_tessface: could not create
>   tessfaces from 144 polygons, dm->type=2 "

happened again

I tried the duplicate again as commented by

```
bpy.data.objects['BMWM1'].select = True
set = bpy.ops.object.duplicate()

for new_obj in set: 
  scn.objects.link(new_obj)
```

still produced a error

> scn.objects.link(new_obj) TypeError: SceneObjects.link(): error with
>   argument 1, "object" -  Function.object expected a Object type, not
>   str

Comment: The return value of bpy.ops.object.duplicate() is not the object that was duplicated by the result of the op, which is a set. That is why you are getting an error while linking to the scene.

Comment: I tried another way,  `set = bpy.ops.object.duplicate(),  for new_obj in set` , but still has a error  **scn.objects.link(new_obj) TypeError: SceneObjects.link(): error with argument 1, "object" - Function.object expected a Object type, not str**

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add. The op does not return the name of the objects created. You will have to find another way to get the duplicated object.

Comment: [Operator return values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18878/15543)  Personally I'd go with your "approach 1", using `bpy.data.objects.new(...)`.  Is the tessface error similar to [the one outlined here?](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?387450-Crash-with-image-textures-locale-related)