# How to set the pivot point when creating a new object with a rotation, using python?

Tags: modeling, python

I am doing some modeling to illustrate a specific math geometry. I want to create a tilted line through a point cable_aufpunkt.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

cabel_rot_x = 5 * np.pi / 180  # 5° rotation around x axis
cable_rot_y = 3 * np.pi / 180  # 3° rotation around y axis
cable_len = 20  # in meter
cable_radius = .03
cable_depth = .5
cable_dist = .55

cable_aufpunkt = np.array([cable_dist, cable_depth, 0])
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(location=cable_aufpunkt,
                                    scale=(cable_radius, cable_radius, cable_len),
                                    rotation=(cabel_rot_x, cable_rot_y, np.pi / 2))
```

However, this line does not touch the point which I specified as `location`. It got rotated away from it by the `rotation=()`. I would like for the object to revolve around its median point. How can I do that? Is that even possible at creation time, or do I need to move and rotate it after creating it?

Comment: try to rotate in a second op, after creation.

Comment: May find these useful. The default origin of a cyl is its median. Object rotation uses origin as pivot. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214497/15543  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214678/15543

Comment: @HananBeer what rotation command would be the right one?

Comment: I think you want `bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=3.14)` (~pi to rotate 180 degrees)